# How to get current principal in Spring Security 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I was trying to get principal via controller.

```
package com.petsimx.takoyomai.controller;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.petsimx.takoyomai.bean.UserInfoDetailsBean;
import com.petsimx.takoyomai.dto.AjaxResponse;
import com.petsimx.takoyomai.service.UserInfoDetailsService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping( "/userevent" )
public class UserEventController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserEventController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private UserInfoDetailsService userInfoDetailsService;
    
    @GetMapping( "/getUserDetails" )
    public ResponseEntity<AjaxResponse<Object>> principalUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserInfoDetailsBean userInfoDetailsBean) {
        logger.info("UserEventController | principalUser ");
        AjaxResponse<Object> ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse<Object>();
        
        try {
//          UserInformationDetail userInformationDetail = userInfoDetailsService.getUserDetails();
            ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse<Object>("success", userInfoDetailsBean);
            logger.info("UserEventController | user :: " + userInfoDetailsBean.toString());
            
            return new ResponseEntity<AjaxResponse<Object>>(ajaxResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error:: " + e.getMessage());
            
            return new ResponseEntity<AjaxResponse<Object>>(ajaxResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

but it says the userInfoDetailsBean is *null*. Also tried this one.

```
@Override
    public UserInformationDetail getUserDetails() {
        logger.info("UserInfoDetailsServiceImpl | getUserDetails | START");
        try {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String username = authentication.getName();
            
            logger.info("UserInfoDetailsServiceImpl | getUserDetails | username :: " + username);
            return userInformationDetailsRepository.findByEmail(username).orElseThrow(() -> new EmailNotFoundException("Email :: " + username + "  not found..."));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            logger.info("UserInfoDetailsServiceImpl | getUserDetails | END");
            return new UserInformationDetail();
        }
    }
```

still getting *null* in authentication.

I have this in my security config.

```
package com.petsimx.takoyomai.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AnonymousConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CsrfConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.petsimx.takoyomai.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    public SecurityConfig() {
    }
    
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return 
                http.csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(r -> r
                    .requestMatchers("/user/create").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/static/**", "/assets/**", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/userevent/getUserDetails").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .formLogin(t -> t
                    .loginPage("/").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll()
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .successHandler(appAuthenticationSuccessHandler()))
                .logout(l -> l
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/"))
                .anonymous(AnonymousConfigurer::disable)
                .build(); 
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider=new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler appAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){
         return new AppAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }
}
```

Also I was trying to get the principal using Thymeleaf and still failed.

```
User: <span sec:authentication="name"></span>
Role(s): <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>
```

I was trying to get some user details after log in to show in my UI.

Comment: you have `.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/userevent/getUserDetails").permitAll()` which means no authorization is performed. The endpoint is public meaning no you wont get a principal. You need to protect the endpoint.